# How to import a class from a sub-directory when programming a CLI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I'm programming a CLI in python 3. In my `main.py` file I'm importing the classes from the sub-directory `classes`. When running the `main.py` file everything works fine. But when I run the CLI itself I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classes'`.

This is the file structure:

```
/setup.py
/install.sh
/project/__main__.py
/project/__init__.py
/project/classes/__init__.py
/project/classes/Class1
```

The setup file runs the `__main__.py` file where I'm importing the classes with this line of code.

```
from classes import Class1
```

Does someone know how to `import` classes in a sub-directory when programming a CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try**

> from project.classes import class1

Answer (score 0):

Add this to :
    /project/classes/**init**.py

```
from .Class1 import Class1

__all__ = ['Class1']
```